# How do I use Searchablespinner feature?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to use the searchable spinner library but it is not working, here is the code. The spinner works well, But I would really like the search feature too from the library

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityHome);
    SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);  
    initControls();

}
```

private void initControls(){

```
   SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            isSpinnerTouched = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(isSpinnerTouched){
                selectedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                code = getCode(selectedItem);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    proceed_button_new = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proceed_button_new);
    proceed_button_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });

    List<Food> data = getData();
    List<String> foodNames = getFoodNamesFromData(data);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, foodNames);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: After thirty years... I've ***finally** found* Carmen San Diego. I guess I can retire now.

Comment: lol, yes. I had to get a job. can you help with this issue?

Comment: First, I have to arrest you for stealing: *The Game Winning Puck From The First Stanley Cup Championship* and you have to pay the fines for all of your [*moving violations*](https://youtu.be/-HGBu75S1FY?t=119) (Also, my notes say you stole *the steps to the tango* - a spinner should be easy)